# Install problem: "Can't compile with this kernel, aborting". dkms (bad exit status: 2)

Tags: kernel, software-installation, raspbian-buster, make

I've been trying to run an install script on my raspberry pi 4, and I keep getting the same error. The script is meant to install a soundcard for a multiple microphone adaptor on the pi, I've got it to work many times before but today I did a fresh install and tried again and it's not working.

I'm following the instructions given at the respeaker seeed website, as follows:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
git clone https://github.com/respeaker/seeed-voicecard.git
cd seeed-voicecard
sudo ./install.sh
```

and I run into problems when it comes to installing the sound card driver:

```
Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/seeed-voicecard/0.3/source ->
/usr/src/seeed-voicecard-0.3

DKMS: add completed.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel. Skipping...

Building module: 
cleaning build area..
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=5.10.11-v71+ -C /lib/modules/5.10.11-v71+/build M=/var/lib/dkms/seeed-voicecard/0.3/build....(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.10.11-v71+ (armv71)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/seeed-voicecard/0.3/build/make.log for more information.
Can't compile with this kernel, aborting 
Please try to compile with the option --compact-kernel
```

I feel like I'm reading another language looking at it so any other help for what to do next would be incredibly useful.

I had a look at the make.log but its super long and I don't know how to find what would be useful in it. Please let me know if there's anything I can do to get this fixed!

Thankyou!

Comment: *"I had a look at the make.log but its super long..."* Try `tail -n 75 /var/lib/dkms/seeed-voicecard/0.3/build/make.log` and edit that in (it's the last 75 lines, unrecoverable failures tend to be one of the last things to happen).  Did you "try to compile with the option --compact-kernel"?  Does that make any difference?  Also, edit in the output of `ls /lib/modules/5.10.11-v71+/build | wc -l` (it will either be a number or an error).

Answer (score 1):

Use `sudo ./install.sh  --compact-kernel` for the install command, like the error suggests you do. An `sudo apt install build-essential` may be an idea to ensure you have all the pieces installed and checking that the `kernel-headers-5.10.11-v71+` however it is named for your running kernel is installed or it will never build.